# Attempt to cast a column only if certain criteria is met

Tags: sql, sql-server

My company uses media management software which stores all metadata for media in 1 table (dimensions, titles, captions, tags, etc...). Because of this, all values are of type `VARCHAR`. It's not a huge problem because each row has a field called `MetaName` which defines what type of data exists in that row. For instance, MetaName 1 is the title field and MetaName 3 is height in pixels.

I'm attempting to find images between certain dimensions in pixels. Since the values are stored as type `VARCHAR` such as `1200px`, I need to replace the `px` and cast to an `INT` before I test a size range like so: `CAST(REPLACE(VALUE, 'px', '') AS INT)`.

Here's a simplified schema and an example to easier understand what I'm talking about:

```
CREATE TABLE Media (
  ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  ImagePath VARCHAR(MAX)
);

CREATE TABLE MetaData (
  ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  MediaId INT REFERENCES Media(ID),
  MetaName INT NOT NULL,
  Value VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
);
```

And test values + my query:

```
INSERT INTO Media (ImagePath)
VALUES
('C:/mypath/myimage.png'), 
('C:/mypath/otherimage.jpg');

INSERT INTO MetaData (MediaId, MetaName, Value)
VALUES 
(1, 1, 'Title1'), (2, 1, 'Title2'),
(1, 2, 'Description1'), (2, 2, 'Description2'),
(1, 3, '1260px'), (2, 3, '1100px'),
(1, 4, '800px'), (2, 4, '1900px');

SELECT * FROM MetaData
WHERE 
 (MetaName = 3 AND CAST(REPLACE(Value, 'px', '') AS INT) BETWEEN 800 AND 1200)
 OR
 (MetaName = 4 AND CAST(REPLACE(Value, 'px', '') AS INT) BETWEEN 800 AND 1200)
```

This should work fine, however, the `CAST` call fails because the query tries to cast ALL of the Value columns so when it runs into "Title1" or "Description1", an error occurs.

How can I cast ONLY on fields with MetaName = 3 or 4? I figured the `MetaName = 3` and the `MetaName = 4` at the beginning of the conditional statements before the `AND` would prevent the `CAST` + `REPLACE` from executing but it happens on all columns regardless.

Comment: Assuming 2012+ you can use TRY_CAST. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use try_convert on SQL Server 2012 onward

```
SELECT * FROM MetaData
WHERE 
 (MetaName = 3 AND try_convert(int,REPLACE(Value, 'px', '')) BETWEEN 800 AND 1200)
 OR
 (MetaName = 4 AND try_convert(int,REPLACE(Value, 'px', '')) BETWEEN 800 AND 1200)
```

Or try_cast

```
SELECT * FROM MetaData
WHERE 
 (MetaName = 3 AND try_cast(REPLACE(Value, 'px', '') as int) BETWEEN 800 AND 1200)
 OR
 (MetaName = 4 AND try_cast(REPLACE(Value, 'px', '') as int) BETWEEN 800 AND 1200)
```

Or, you can wrap that cast in a `CASE`

```
SELECT * FROM MetaData
where
(MetaName = 3 AND case when MetaName = 3 then CAST(REPLACE(Value, 'px', '') AS INT) end BETWEEN 800 AND 1200)
 OR
(MetaName = 4 AND case when MetaName = 4 then CAST(REPLACE(Value, 'px', '') AS INT) end BETWEEN 800 AND 1200)
```

Or, use `IIF`

```
SELECT * FROM MetaData
where
(MetaName = 3 AND iif(MetaName = 3,CAST(REPLACE(Value, 'px', '') AS INT),null) BETWEEN 800 AND 1200)
 OR
(MetaName = 4 AND iif(MetaName = 4,CAST(REPLACE(Value, 'px', '') AS INT),null) BETWEEN 800 AND 1200)
```

Or, break up the filtering using a `CTE`.

```
;with cte as(
SELECT * FROM MetaData
where MetaName in (3,4))

select *
from cte
where CAST(REPLACE(Value, 'px', '') AS INT) BETWEEN 800 AND 1200
```

Comment: Well done sir. Even simpler would be to use IN for MetaName. :)

Comment: haha i did that with a cte @SeanLange but i feel like that's now how you meant it. Care to show? Or do you mean like how kiran did below? I see tha tnow.

Comment: I actually am using a CTE in my actual code but I can't only select pixel dimensions because I need to search by dimensions, description keywords, tags, etc... However `TRY_CONVERT` works perfectly! Thank you

Comment: No worries @JakeMiller happy hunting

Comment: I was thinking you would only need two predicates that way. One with the conversion logic AND MetaName in (3, 4)

Comment: I ended up having to use `TRY_CAST` because we've got an older version of SQL Server that doesn't have `TRY_CONVERT`. Would you mind adding that to your answer as an option for anyone that sees this post?

Comment: Absolutely @JakeMiller will do shortly just tag the version in your post too

Answer (score 2):

```
 SELECT * FROM MetaData
 WHERE 
 ( case when (MetaName = 3 or MetaName = 4)  then  CAST(REPLACE(Value, 'px', '') AS INT) else NULL end )  
  BETWEEN 800 AND 1200
```

Comment: `ELSE NULL` would be safer incase the boundaries change in the future.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is use TRY_CAST instead of CAST.

```
SELECT * FROM MetaData
WHERE 
 (MetaName = 3 AND TRY_CAST(REPLACE(Value, 'px', '') AS INT) BETWEEN 800 AND 1200)
 OR
 (MetaName = 4 AND TRY_CAST(REPLACE(Value, 'px', '') AS INT) BETWEEN 800 AND 1200)
```

When I do this it only returns MetaNames 3 and 4 as part of the result set. I believe this functionality was introduced in SQL Server 2012.